# Http Redirect in IIS6

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-6, http-redirect

I need to implement a functionality in one of my web app in such a way that if i host a webapp in the IIS (let say

```
http://localhost/mywebapp
```

), it should also open through

```
http://localhost
```

I simply cannot install my web app on the root web app i.e.

```
http://localhost
```

For this, I found a setting in web.config for IIS7 named as HttpRedirect. Which i set programatically during application installation.

But, I wouldn't able find the same setting for IIS6 which i can set programmatically. I found a solution through which it can be done but its manually. http://www.serverintellect.com/support/iis/iis-url-redirect/

Any idea on how to create this programatically in IIS6.

I am using c# as a language in .net4.

Comment: Do you really need to set the redirect path programatically?

Comment: Since you are trying to do this "programatically", having some code of your solution would help. Are you using WCF ? Web Api ? Are you looking for a solution to automate the manual aspect of iis url redirect in your installation ? If yes, are you using wix or installshield ?

Comment: Yes. That's why I am looking for a solution.

Comment: @guiomie: Let's not make it complex. Consider a scenario,

There are multiple webapps running on IIS6. Inside one of the app, there's another app which I hosted. Now, what I want is, whenever someone enter's the machine-name, the site which I hosted will get open. For this, I need to set the url-redirect in the root web app which is running under port 80. Correct. I can do this process manually in IIS6 as mentioned in the url in my post. But, i want to automate this process. It could be just a normal console application  not any installsheild or wix.